# How to add our own custom JSON message to Blueprint API in Sails.js?

Tags: sails.js

I want to send to client side like this:

```json
{
  "success": true,
  "message": "Your Message",
  "result": ""
}
```

Comment: It's recommended when you need to have more control over your actions in Sails.js to use a custom action. See here for more info on this
https://sailsjs.com/documentation/reference/blueprint-api

Comment: I tried but it is not overriding to Blueprint APIs.

Answer (score 2):

When it comes to Blueprint APIs, we will not be able to send custom responses. In order to send custom responses, you have to define custom actions/controller methods with the desired response and define a custom route for that action/controller method in `config/routes.js`. If the Blueprint APIs still override the custom methods, you can disable the Blueprint APIs by changing the value of `actions` to **false** in `config/blueprints.js`. This will disable Blueprint APIs completely.

```
module.exports.blueprints = {

    actions: true,

    // rest: true,

    // shortcuts: true,
};
```

If you want to disable Blueprint routes on a per-controller basis, checkout https://sailsjs.com/documentation/reference/blueprint-api#?disabling-blueprint-routes-on-a-percontroller-basis for more info.

Even though Blueprint APIs come in handy during development, it is recommended to use custom routes while moving to production, since custom routes are more secure than Blueprint APIs.